# Is there a way to check what tags are in a file using taglib-sharp? Something like TagTypes.Id3v1.Exists?

Tags: .net, taglib-sharp

I've been using taglib-sharp to remove ID3 tags from MP3 files. Everything seems pretty straight forward besides knowing what tags there is in the file.

Comment: Do you ask for a way to get all existing tags in a file or just how to delete all existing tags?

Comment: I'm just working with mp3 right now so just ID3v1.x/ID3v2.x. I know how how to remove the tags. I was just wondering if the was a way to check if the MP3 had any tags in it. If not, I would just skip that mp3 to make program faster. I guess I'll just manually check for the TAG and ID3 heasders manually.

Comment: You could check your files for all the tags documented here: http://taglib-sharp.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.0.4.0-1/classTagLib_1_1File.html (Maybe .GetTag is the command you are looking for: http://taglib-sharp.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.0.4.0-1/classTagLib_1_1File_a7d0e24df2727c1bcc9b00e813483e0af.html#a7d0e24df2727c1bcc9b00e813483e0af

Comment: Thanks for the great information! I think that's exactly what I was looking for. I'm gonna have to update the version of taglib-sharp I'm using.

Comment: @Peter : All your links have died. Do you happen to have update links?

Comment: @TaW You can always use the wayback machine for such pages: https://web.archive.org/web/20160518061134/http://taglib-sharp.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.0.4.0-1/classTagLib_1_1File.html

Comment: Yeah, usually a blessing; but this time I get (server) errors on most pages and very little content otherwise..

Answer (score 0):

There's a property `TagLib.File.TagTypesOnDisk` that returns the tag types that were in the tag when it was first read or last saved.  There's also `TagLib.File.TagTypes` which returns the tag types that are currently in the file representation and will be written when `Save()` is called.  The difference between the two is generally any new tag types that a file format might add by default.

Removing those tags is simply a matter of calling `TagLib.File.RemoveTags` before saving. E.g. `file.RemoveTags(TagLib.TagTypes.Id3v1)`